# Node-RED PCA9685 not working

Tags: node.js, servo

I am using node red on a Raspberry Pie 3. I have a PCA9685 board. I did the operations as described [here](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-pca9685).

1. I have an pca9685 integrated.
2. I feed the energy from the external adapter with 5 volts.
3. I made the connections like [the template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fauberso/node-red-contrib-pca9685/master/images/hardware.png).
4. I wrote the project as follows:

   ```
   [{"id":"feaadd05.f046d","type":"inject","z":"1fe6197f.0d25c7","name":"100%","topic":"","payload":"100","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":1045,"y":40,"wires":[["46bd9273.6b279c"]]},
    {"id":"71dd9036.680b3","type":"inject","z":"1fe6197f.0d25c7","name":"50%","topic":"","payload":"50","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":1045,"y":80,"wires":[["46bd9273.6b279c"]]},
    {"id":"89f319a8.9eea78","type":"inject","z":"1fe6197f.0d25c7","name":"Off","topic":"","payload":"0","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":1045,"y":120,"wires":[["46bd9273.6b279c"]]},
    {"id":"1c347df.4004b82","type":"inject","z":"1fe6197f.0d25c7","name":"120�","topic":"","payload":"2100","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":1045,"y":180,"wires":[["d11db9bf.d2cc58"]]},
    {"id":"ec6ef0f2.d5b56","type":"inject","z":"1fe6197f.0d25c7","name":"60�","topic":"","payload":"1500","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":1045,"y":220,"wires":[["d11db9bf.d2cc58"]]},
    {"id":"4b72d6f3.2020e8","type":"inject","z":"1fe6197f.0d25c7","name":"0�","topic":"","payload":"900","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":1045,"y":260,"wires":[["d11db9bf.d2cc58"]]},
    {"id":"eaa2a00e.3dfca","type":"inject","z":"1fe6197f.0d25c7","name":"Off","topic":"","payload":"0","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":1045,"y":300,"wires":[["d11db9bf.d2cc58"]]},
    {"id":"46bd9273.6b279c","type":"PCA9685 out","z":"1fe6197f.0d25c7","name":"PWM Output 2 (Led)","pca9685":"6ce45bce.cdff94","channel":"2","payload":"","unit":"percent","onStep":"0","x":1260,"y":80,"wires":[]},
    {"id":"d11db9bf.d2cc58","type":"PCA9685 out","z":"1fe6197f.0d25c7","name":"PWM Output 4 (Servo)","pca9685":"6ce45bce.cdff94","channel":"4","payload":"","unit":"microseconds","onStep":"0","x":1270,"y":240,"wires":[]},
    {"id":"6ce45bce.cdff94","type":"PCA9685","z":"","deviceNumber":"1","address":"64","frequency":"50"}]
   ```
5. But I get an error.

   ```
   Error message: 28.02.2018 15:16:29node: 780c40d.34cd2c
   msg : string[55]
   "Error stopping node: ReferenceError: pwm is not defined"
   ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add some additional information what you were trying to do and during which step of the guide you encountered the error? It would be best to add all steps you did to your question so that it remains valid even if the link stops working.

Comment: Ok thanx :) i will try now.

Comment: Thank you :) You can use the edit function (right below your question text) to add additional information. I already added your information to the question.